# Django: optimizing queries

Tags: django

I want to list the number of items for each list. How can I find this number in a single query, rather than a query for each list?

Here is a simplified version of my current template code:

```
{% for list in lists %}
<li>
{{ listname }}:
{% with list.num_items as item_count %}
{{ item_count }} item{{ item_count|pluralize }}
{% endwith %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

lists is passed as: List.objects.filter(user=user)

and num_items is a property of the List model:

```
def _get_num_items(self):
    return self.item_set.filter(archived=False).count()
num_items = property(_get_num_items)
```

This queries `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "my_app_item" WHERE...` n times, where n is the number of lists. Is it possible to make a single query here?

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Ignacio, He is asking how to obtain the "grouped aggregates within a single query" which the documentation you point to, doesn't talk about.

Comment: @Lakshman: Only if you don't read it.

Comment: BTW, you should make the title of your question a bit more specific, something along the lines of  "inner join + count + where + group_by query using Django ORM"

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in your view and send the dictionary, instead.

```
Model.objects.values_list('item').annotate(Count('num_items'))
```

This will produce the SQL same as, (or equivalent to) the one you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, I tried to take into account all your constraints: filtering on fields of List, on fields of Item, counting items , and grouping by list.

The solution I see is that you could use  values()  (here is the django doc about this : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

```
from django.db.models import Count
lists = list(List.objects.filter(user=user))
items=Item.objects.values(list).filter(archived=False,list__in=lists).annotate(count=Count("id")) 
#you will get a list of dicts of the form [{'count':2,'list':5},...] where 5 is the id of the list
#now, you can match you list with you item counts in python
list_items_count_dict={}
for item in items:
    list_items_count_dict[item['list']]=item['count']
for list in lists : 
    list.item_count = list_items_count_dict.get(list.id)
```

That will make only 2 queries, one for getting the lists, the other for computing the item counts. Afterwards, you will have two loops (that could probably be replaced by list comprehension one-liners ), but only for the lists you are interested in.

afterwards, in your template, you can use

```
{{list.item_count}}
```

There might be a more elegant option, but that is what I have found right now. I am also certain that you could reduce the number of query to one by using custom sql.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code, but I have tested similar code on similar models. You could have problems because `list` is one of the keyword of the Python language.